# How to set httpOnly flag true for cookie in Java?

Tags: java, hibernate, cookies, cookie-httponly

I tried the setHtpOnly(true) option but it doesn't seem to be working as it isn't a method in Cookie. I did see a few solutions using path but I'm not sure about that either.

This is my code.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie (name, entity);
cookie.setPath("/");
httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
```

What can I do to set the httpOnly flag as true for the above code?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Java are you using? Are you seeing a specific error on compilation? This method seems to exist in Java EE since at least 6 and Servlet 3.1:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setHttpOnly(boolean)